# Read daily steps count without Google Fit app

Tags: fitness, google-fit

Hi Android enthusiasts !

I'm developing an app that read Google Fit OS layer data (local data written on the phone, not Google Fit application itself).

Does phone's steps sensor natively write daily steps count to Google Fit API or is this only achieved by a tierce application (Google Fit app or any basic pedometer application) ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Comment: Apart from that: I don't think so. There are several privacy-friendly step counters out there which otherwise couldn't work.